# ayuda con el formato correcto de php EXCEL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

me habian ayudado a mejorar el codigo de una exportacion de php a excel ahora mi duda es
ya que los tengo me sale un formato diferente

maso menos como la siguiente imagen me aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces lo que necesito es que me aparescan bien los campos de en cada una de las columnas

para que se pueda ver bien dentro del excel

```
<?php
    
    $mysqli=new mysqli('127.0.0.1:4473','root' , '', 'convenios'); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos
    
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    

    //Incluimos librería y archivo de conexión
    require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    
    //Consulta
    $sql = "SELECT usuario, fecha_soli,cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt,sdo_total, mont_pagar,de_desc, fecha_pago,tipo_solicitud,
    actualizado_a, estatus FROM convenio order by  actualizado_a ASC LIMIT 50" ;
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $fila = 7; //Establecemos en que fila inciara a imprimir los datos
    
    
    //Objeto de PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel  = new PHPExcel();
    
    //Propiedades de Documento
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("ING.Roberto Mendoza")->setDescription("Reporte de Convenios");
    
    //Establecemos la pestaña activa y nombre a la pestaña
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("convenio");
    
    $estiloTituloReporte = array(
    'font' => array(
    'name'      => 'Arial',
    'bold'      => true,
    'italic'    => false,
    'strike'    => false,
    'size' =>13
    ),
    'fill' => array(
    'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID
    ),
    'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE
    )
    ),
    'alignment' => array(
    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
    )
    );
    
    $estiloTituloColumnas = array(
    'font' => array(
    'name'  => 'Arial',
    'bold'  => true,
    'size' =>10,
    'color' => array(
    'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
    )
    ),
    'fill' => array(
    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'color' => array('rgb' => '538DD5')
    ),
    'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
    ),
    'alignment' =>  array(
    'horizontal'=> PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    'vertical'  => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
    )
    );
    
    $estiloInformacion = new PHPExcel_Style();
    $estiloInformacion->applyFromArray( array(
    'font' => array(
    'name'  => 'Arial',
    'color' => array(
    'rgb' => '000000'
    )
    ),
    'fill' => array(
    'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID
    ),
    'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
    ),
    'alignment' =>  array(
    'horizontal'=> PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    'vertical'  => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
    )
    ));
    
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloReporte);
    
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE DE CONVENIOS');
    
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A6', 'usuario');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', 'FECHA SOLICITUD');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', 'CUENTA');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D6', 'FECHA PROMESA');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E6', 'NOMBRE DE TITUTAR');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F6', 'SALDO TOTAL');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G6', 'MONTO A PAGAR');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H6', '% DE DESCUENTO');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I6', 'FECHA DE PAGO');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J6', 'TIPO DE SOLICITUD');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K6', 'ULTI. ACTUALIZACION');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L6', 'STATUS');
    //Recorremos los resultados de la consulta y los imprimimos
    while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $rows['usuario']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $rows['fecha_soli']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $rows['cuenta']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $rows['fecha_prom']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $rows['nombre_tt']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $rows['sdo_total']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$fila, $rows['mont_pagar']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$fila, $rows['de_desc']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$fila, $rows['fecha_pago']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$fila, $rows['tipo_solicitud']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$fila, $rows['actualizado_a']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$fila, $rows['estatus']);
        
        $fila++; //Sumamos 1 para pasar a la siguiente fila
    }
    
    $fila = $fila-1;
    
    
    
    
    
    // incluir gráfico
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Solicitud convenios.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);

$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit;
?>
```

lo que busco es que se vea con el siguiente formato
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para que quede bien el reporte mencionaban que phpexcel ya es obsoleto pero phpsheet necesito instalar laravel y aqui tengo phppuro

gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

te mando el ejemplo del mio, me funciona correctamente

```html
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Font;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

require_once '../src/Bootstrap.php';

$helper = new Sample();
if ($helper->isCli()) {
    $helper->log('This example should only be run from a Web Browser' . PHP_EOL);

    return;
}
// Create new Spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

// Set document properties
$spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Maarten Balliauw')
    ->setLastModifiedBy('Maarten Balliauw')
    ->setTitle('Office 2007 XLSX Test Document')
    ->setSubject('Office 2007 XLSX Test Document')
    ->setDescription('Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.')
    ->setKeywords('office 2007 openxml php')
    ->setCategory('Test result file');

// Add some data
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A1', 'Abrev.')
->setCellValue('B1', 'Curso')
->setCellValue('C1', 'Fecha')
->setCellValue('D1', 'Fecha limite')
->setCellValue('E1', 'Estado')
->setCellValue('F1', 'fecha entrega');

include 'database.php';

$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT fecha, cursoabrev, fechaup, idalumno, cursoname FROM eventos left join curso ON eventos.idcurso = curso.idcurso left join eventos_alumnos ON eventos.ideventos = eventos_alumnos.ideventos';
    $i=2;
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$cursoabrev = $row['cursoabrev'];
$cursoname = $row['cursoname'];
$fechaprin = strtotime($row['fecha']);
$fechaprin = (date ("d-m-Y", $fechaprin));
$fechalimi = strtotime($row['fecha'])+(86400*2);
$fechalimi = (date ("d-m-Y", $fechalimi));
if(!is_null($row['idalumno'])){ $estado="entregado"; }
else { $estado="pendiente"; };
if(!is_null($row['fechaup'])){$fechaup = date("d-m-Y" ,strtotime($row['fechaup']));}
else { $fechaup = " ";};

    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue("A$i", $cursoabrev)
    ->setCellValue("B$i", $cursoname)
    ->setCellValue("C$i", $fechaprin)
    ->setCellValue("D$i", $fechalimi)
    ->setCellValue("E$i", $estado)
    ->setCellValue("F$i", $fechaup);

    $i++;

}
Database::disconnect();
$i = $i-1;

// Set column widths
//$helper->log('Set column widths');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);


// Set thin black border outline around column
//$helper->log('Set thin black border outline around column');
$styleThinBlackBorderOutline = [
    'borders' => [
        'outline' => [
            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => ['argb' => 'FF000000'],
        ],
    ],
];
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:F'.$i)->applyFromArray($styleThinBlackBorderOutline);

// Set fills
//$helper->log('Set fills');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFa1ecbf');


// Set fonts
//$helper->log('Set fonts');
//$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setName('Candara');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFont()->setSize(12);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFont()->setBold(true);


// Rename worksheet
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Listado_tareas');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="listado_tareas.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], mas que solo publicarle el código al OP, en el sitio se espera una respuesta mas completa, por ejemplo ¿cómo integra esto a su proyecto?, ya que como notas los comentarios de tu script están en inglés y aquí lo ideal es en español

Comment: El OP requiere de una respuesta más elaborada con una explicación, por favor edita tu respuesta y hazla más entendible.

Comment: lo adecue a mi tabla pero me salio error